# Indenting/breaking jquery chains for readability

Tags: javascript, jquery, readability

I'm curious as to how other people indent/break long jQuery chains, as I can never decide what is more readable (particularly when using .end() to "close" a block of methods e.g.

```
$(this).not(":has(.pointer)").append(pointerHtml)
                .end()
            .closest("li").toggleClass("selected")
            .siblings().removeClass("selected")
            .andSelf().removeClass("pre-selected").animate({
                                 left: 12
                                 opacity: 0.5
                            })
                .end().end()
            .filter(".selected").prev().addClass("pre-selected")
                            .end().children().load("/homepage.html", function() {
                                       //code
                             }).end().end().addClass("processed");
```

How would YOU format this?

*edit included a method with a callback to make it a bit more interesting

Comment: NOTE: This is **not** a question that should have been asked on Stack Overflow as there's not actually a problem with the code. It's a question of style. It might be OK for [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/), but it *is* on topic here.

Comment: Not sure that editing your question after people have answered it is a very nice thing to do. Your example now just seems contrived. In any event, past a certain point you have to start refactoring behavior out to simplify things.

Comment: Also, if you find an answer useful, you might consider [accepting it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work).

Answer (score 7):

I use indent to signify hierarchy.

```
$(this).not(":has(.pointer)")
  .append(pointerHtml).end()
  .closest("li")
    .toggleClass("selected")
    .siblings()
      .removeClass("selected")
      .andSelf().removeClass("pre-selected")
    .end()
  .end()
  .filter(".selected")
    .prev().addClass("pre-selected");
```

Answer (score 0):

For indentation I'd say that selector would be equivalent of opening a block (`{`), while `.end()` -- equivalent of `}`